# getting required namespace not available error on Reagent Clojurescript project

Tags: clojurescript, reagent

I'm trying to break out some of the page components from `core.cljs` from https://github.com/reagent-project/reagent-frontend-template , but am getting this error:
`The required namespace "reagent-project.utils.path-for" is not available, it was required by "reagent_project/pages/home.cljs".`

my files are as follows:

#### path-for.cljs

```
(ns reagent-project.utils.path-for
  (:require
   [reitit.frontend :as reitit]))

(defn path-for [route & [params]]
  (if params
    (:path (reitit/match-by-name router route params))
    (:path (reitit/match-by-name router route))))
```

#### home.cljs

```
(ns reagent-project.pages.home
  (:require
   [reagent-project.utils.path-for :refer [path-for]]
   [reagent.core :as reagent :refer [atom]]))

(defn home-page []
  (fn []
    [:span.main
     [:h1 "Welcome to reagent-project"]
     [:ul
      [:li [:a {:href (path-for :items)} "Items of reagent-project"]]
      [:li [:a {:href "/broken/link"} "Broken link"]]]]))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you have the correct filename and is it on the [classpath](https://code.thheller.com/blog/shadow-cljs/2021/05/13/paths-paths-paths.html)?

Assuming you have `:source-paths ["src"]` then the expected filename would be `src/reagent_project/utils/path_for.cljs`? Note that `-` is required to be turned into a `_` for `.clj(s)` source files.

Comment: renaming `path-for.cljs` to `path_for.cljs` fixed it. thank you.